# How to make ENumerable operations tread safe SynchronizedCollection?

Tags: c#, list, asynchronous, concurrency, synchronization

When I use `SynchronizedCollection`, I can catch the exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
```

in `foreach` cycle.

If you look at the source code of SynchronizedCollection class, namely in GetEnumerator method (there is two of them actually one is explicit interface implementation), you’ll see this:

```
List<T> items;

IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
{
    return ((IList)this.items).GetEnumerator();
}

public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    lock (this.sync)
    {
        return this.items.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

[It returns enumerator of inner List which is not thread safe](https://allforprogramming.wordpress.com/2015/11/30/synchronizedcollection-gotcha/)!

Edit. I am asking not what can I do in concurrent situations. I am asking

> How to make it thread safe?

Comment: Try collections in [System.Collections.Concurrent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8)?

Comment: @LeisenChang I am using the SynchronizedCollection to replace List<T>. There is no ConcurentList<T>

Comment: How about use `ToArray()` to copy the entire list?

Comment: @LeisenChang that can be a solution, but I have several hundrets of references and want to make changes only in one place, in property defenition.

Comment: "property definition", what exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: Replace the "return this.items.GetEnumerator();" statement with `foreach (var element in this.items) yield return element;`

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen public SynchronizedCollection<T> property

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen can you please, write the answer how to extend the class? I will accept the answer.

Comment: That class looks broken to be honest. That GetEnumerator method is incorrect. I do see the reference source and also the decompiler showing the same code so it's not about reference source being out of touch, this is just broken.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand why my change would be better than just use ToArray inside that method, it seems you want to make the change somewhere else.

Comment: In general, replacing the "this.items.GetEnumerator()" method with "this.items.ToArray().GetEnumerator()" would probably be better, as this makes a snapshot of the values, and you already have an answer that says this is what you could do. My change is just a more elaborate way to consume the collection inside the lock.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I just want to leave all my foreach, while, etc unchanged and change it only in one place. If I do foreach(int i in obj.SyncCollectionOfI.ToArray), I have to change a lot of code

Comment: You'll have to do that inside your sync-lock. Code on the outside does not have to change, you can do that with toarray as well, simply call ToArray inside that sync-lock and return that instead.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen my sync-lock is not my. It is the source code of SynchronizedCollection class

Comment: Agh, yes of course. Well, then you have to make the snapshot on the outside. Or you will have to encapsulate that collection with something that *is* thread safe.

Comment: Let me rephrase; you can't fix the bug in SynchronizedCollection so whatever you do will involve replacing or encapsulating that collection, so code elsewhere that still expects this to be SynchronizedCollection will either have to live this problem, or be changed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192427/discussion-between-buciz-and-lasse-vagsaether-karlsen).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is two solution for this:

1. Use [ConcurrentBag<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent?view=netframework-4.8) or other collection in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace. (Notice that the elements in ConcurrentBag will not be ordered.)
2. Create a snap shot when retrieving data.

The second one is much safer, in the cost of performance.

If you are using .NetCore, [ImmutableList<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist-1?view=netcore-2.2) is a better way for snap shot, and can avoid shallow copy problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but that does not answer my origin question.

Answer (score 0):

I used SynchronizedCollection class and used `foreach (var element in this.items) yield return element;`
here
public new IEnumerator GetEnumerator()

used constructors from base classes and that was enough to make it thread-safe

Comment: Thank you  Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen